# How to access a virtual directory inside a blob container?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to download a file which is inside a subfolder of a blob container using Azure C# functions. This is all in a storage account.

```
BlobUriBuilder blobUriBuilder = new BlobUriBuilder(fileUri);  
string containerName = blobUriBuilder.BlobContainerName;
string blobName = blobUriBuilder.BlobName; 
BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(blobName);
// Check if the document exists
if (!await blobClient.ExistsAsync())
{
    return new NotFoundObjectResult(new { error = "Verify the file name", details = "Unable to locate the file in the provided location" });
} 
BlobDownloadInfo download = await blobClient.DownloadAsync();
```

---

I am able to download file from a root directory, but when I try to download a file inside a subfolder, it throws an error.

Comment: You haven't given us any error details - so we can't really help you until you at least give us a _verbatim_ error message, errors codes, examples of URI formats, what edition/kind of storage-account you're using, etc etc.

Comment: Blob storage has no folders, either in Azure or Amazon. A bucket/container is just a flat ser of files. Folder storage just can't scale to the millions of files that can be stored in a single container. Folders are *emulated* by searching for all blobs that start with a specific "path" prefix

Comment: If you check [BlobContainerClient.GetBlobsAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobcontainerclient.getblobsasync?view=azure-dotnet) you'll see it has a `prefix` parameter. That should be set to the "full folder path". The [GetBlobsByHierarchyAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobcontainerclient.getblobsbyhierarchyasync?view=azure-dotnet) method behaves the same but returns results as a hierarchy based on the "path separator".

Comment: The path separator doesn't have to be `/`. If your file names start with a date you could use `-` to read blobs as if they were stored by year,month and day

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That's not universally true anymore - if you pay enough money for your storage account then you can have directory structures just as real as in any other file-system: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-introduction

Comment: Please edit your question and include the name of the container and the blob. I have a suspicion that you’re adding the folder name to your container name.

Answer (score 0):

**I could achieve your requirement with below steps:**

- Uploaded a text file in the subfolder of my container in the Azure Storage Account:

[image]

- The  file name along with the folder name should be passed in the GetBlobClient() as shown below:

```
BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient($"{subfolderName}/{fileName}");
```

**My Code Snippet:**

```cs
var connectionString = "<storage_connection_string>";
var url = "https://<storage>.blob.core.windows.net/<Blob_name>/<Folder1>/<folder2><file.exe>";
BlobUriBuilder blobUriBuilder = new BlobUriBuilder(new Uri(url));
string containerName = blobUriBuilder.BlobContainerName;
string blobName = blobUriBuilder.BlobName;
BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(blobName);

if (!await blobClient.ExistsAsync())
{
    return new NotFoundObjectResult(new { error = "Verify the file name", details = "Unable to locate the file in the provided location" });
}
BlobDownloadResult downloadResult = await blobClient.DownloadContentAsync();
string downloadedData = downloadResult.Content.ToString();
log.LogInformation("Downloaded data: " + downloadedData);
```

- In this case, **BlobName** contains the full path of the blob within the directory/folder. i.e., `"subfolder/file.exe"`.

[image]

**Console Output:**

- ***Able to read the content of the downloaded file.***

```cs
Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.5530 Commit hash: N/A +c8883e7f3c06e2XXXX3806c19d8d91418c (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.28.5.21962

[2024-03-07T11:48:50.219Z] Found C:\Users\uname\...\FunctionApp.csproj. Using for user secrets file configuration.

Functions:

        Function1: [GET,POST] http://localhost:7236/api/Function1

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-03-07T12:11:43.018Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000F72731CC'.
[2024-03-07T12:11:59.840Z] Executing 'Function1' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=5744c98b-ccXXX8f-fb4cfe85d25b)
[2024-03-07T12:11:59.941Z] C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.
[2024-03-07T12:12:22.316Z] Downloaded data: Secret-1
[2024-03-07T12:12:22.333Z] Secret-2
[2024-03-07T12:12:22.344Z] Secret-3
[2024-03-07T12:12:22.546Z] Executed 'Function1' (Succeeded, Id=5744c98b-cca6-43XXXXX4cfe85d25b, Duration=22797ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 BlobUriBuilder blobUriBuilder = new BlobUriBuilder(fileUri);

 string containerName = blobUriBuilder.BlobContainerName;

 // Split the BlobName into subfolder and blob name
 string[] pathParts = blobUriBuilder.BlobName.Split('/');

 // The first part is the subfolder, the rest is the blob name
 string subfolder = pathParts.Length > 1 ? pathParts[0] : null;
 string blobName = pathParts.Length > 1 ? string.Join('/', pathParts.Skip(1)) : pathParts[0];

 // If subfolder is not null, concatenate it with the blob name
 string blobPath = subfolder != null ? $"{subfolder}/{blobName}" : blobName;

 var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
 BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
 BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(blobPath);

 // Check if the document exists
 if (!await blobClient.ExistsAsync())
 {
     return new NotFoundObjectResult(new { error = "Verify the file name", details = "Unable to locate the file in the provided location" });
 }

 BlobDownloadInfo download = await blobClient.DownloadAsync();

 string fileShareName = data.MoveFileRequest.TargetFileShareLocation.Split('/')[0];
 string targetSubfolder = data.MoveFileRequest.TargetFileShareLocation.Contains("/")
     ? data.MoveFileRequest.TargetFileShareLocation.Substring(data.MoveFileRequest.TargetFileShareLocation.IndexOf('/') + 1)
     : "";

 ShareClient shareClient = new ShareClient(connectionString, fileShareName);

 // Check if the file share exists
 if (!await shareClient.ExistsAsync())
 {
     return new NotFoundObjectResult(new { error = "Verify the target file share location", details = "Unable to move the file, File share does not exist in the directory" });
 }

 ShareDirectoryClient directoryClient = shareClient.GetRootDirectoryClient();
```

This worked. Thanks guys for the input.